# Problem with relative path in System.file.io of asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, relative-path

I'm storing the file path in the database as ~/FolderName/FileName and when i try to open the file using System.IO.FileInfo(filePath) in this manner. It is not able to decipher the file path. Moreover i'm using this statement in a class DownloadFile, so i'm not able to use Page.Server.MapPath. Is there a work around for this problem.

These are the following lines of code that i'm using:

```
if (dr1.Read())
{
    String filePath = dr1[0].ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
    String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\"" + fileName + "\"";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
    System.IO.FileInfo fileToDownload = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
    string fullName = fileToDownload.FullName;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(fileToDownload.FullName);
    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

where the filepath is of the format `~/ComponentFolderForDownloading/FileName.exe`

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Any reason you can't use MapPath in your downloadFile class?

Comment: @Joe can some one explain to me what is the difference between Server.MapPath("~/ComponentFolder/File1.exe") and Server.MapPath("~\ComponentFolder\File1.exe") with this / and \ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use `Server.MapPath` for determining the file location, you need to use something else. The `FileInfo` class can not take an ASP.NET virtual path in its constructor. It needs the real, physical path of the file.

You'll need to strip the `~/` from the front of the path; perhaps exchange the `/` for a `\`, and then use `Path.Combine` with the root directory of your application to find the physical location. But that assumes that your locations are in physical directories - not virtual ones.

`Server.MapPath` was, of course, made specifically to do this.

An alternative would be to store the real, physical locations of the files in the DB; either in addition to or in stead of the virtual, ASP.NET ones.

Comment: can some one explain to me what is the difference between Server.MapPath("~/ComponentFolder/File1.exe") and Server.MapPath("~\ComponentFolder\File1.exe") with this / and \ ??

Answer (score 1):

If you know you are running in IIS, you can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/someurl");
```

Comment: can some one explain to me what is the difference between Server.MapPath("~/ComponentFolder/File1.exe") and Server.MapPath("~\ComponentFolder\File1.exe") with this / and \ ??

Comment: Back slashes are a Windows filesystem convention. I always use forward slashes for Internet URLs.