# Why will the addressing method that works for images not work for text files?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I am developing an interest inventory web app. There are to be 60 frames with 2 pictures and text descriptions of each picture on each frame. I have no problem displaying the pictures, but when using the same addressing methodology for the text files, it does not work.

This works to display the images:

```
img src="~/Images/RIPAImages/@m@imagePathL" style="width:450px; height:270px; enable-background:new"
```

If I give an absolute path to a folder on my computer, it works like this and reads the text file:

```
rtxt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:/users/Owner/Documents/Documents/Beulah Farms/10" + @txtPathR);
```

But when I use the same addressing method to reach the text files located in the application file system, it does not work. It says the location does not exist.
Here is the method I used:

```
rtxt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"~/Images/RIPAImages/"+@m + @txtPathR);
```

I realize that I do not have the quote marks the same as when reading the image file, but if I do the quote marks the same way, it really blows up.

I originally developed this as a windows program. Then I did it on VS 2010 when the V actually meant Visual. I was using Visual Basic at that time. Then I screwed up and downloaded 2015 and then 2017. I am trying to move to C# also.

I would appreciate any help with this that anyone can give. Thanks

Comment: This other question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5859991/945456

Answer (score 0):

Few things before we get into the answer to your question:

1. If you are using VS 2017 then you should be using [String Interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx). Its the best! You will not switch back once you start using it.
2. You seem to be calling the System.IO from razor. I hope not.(you really shouldn't) That's what the "controller" in MVC is for.
3. You can do this processing in the controller and then pass this to the view if not in a viewmodel at least in ViewData.

Now, the `~` in HTML tags, refers to your `home` directory. In case of IIS or ASP.NET core that's the `wwwroot` directory.

When you use that in the System.IO API, it has no significance and is considered as any other path. Therefore, if your project is running at `c:\samples\myproj` then `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"~/Images/RIPAImages/..."` will translate to `c:\samples\myproj\~\Images\RIPAImages` which obviously does not exist. Therefore, the best approach will be to do the following in your controller.

```
namespace foo.Controllers
{
    public class BarController : Controller
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _env;

        public BarController(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var text1 = "site.css";
            ViewData["textInfo"] = Path.Combine( _env.WebRootPath,"css" , text1); //becomes myapppath/wwwroot/css/site.css
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the view you would call:

```
@ViewData["textPath"].ToString()
```

Comment: Check out Server.MapPath

Comment: Is there supposed to be a using statement in the controller example? I get a bundle of squiggle lines. They are under IHosingEnvironment, _env, & env. Then it will not even allow me to type Path.Combine. It changes that to --, oh well I went back to see what it kept changing it to and then it allowed me to type Path.Combine.

Comment: Yes, all of which you should be able to resolve through Visual studio quick actions (light bulb) on the left of the appropriate line ...

Answer (score 0):

For Web application you can get file path using `Server.MapPath`.

**For Example :**

```
rtxt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/RIPAImages/"),@m,@txtPathR));
```

**OR**

For any type of application like web, windows form ,console you can get path by using `DirectoryInfo`.

**For Example:**

```
 var startupPath =new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(newUriBuilder(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Path))).Parent.FullName;//path of that folder which contain bin folder
    var rtxt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(startupPath+"\\Images\\RIPAImages\\"+@m+@txtPathR);
```

**N.B :** `@m` and `@txtPathR` your path variable.